# Design patterns: Making code implementation-agnostic

Tags: design-patterns, interface

I want my code to be implementation-agnostic. In this particular case, I want to abstract data storage.
I created IDatasource interface that could be implemented later by SqlStorage, MongoStorage, etc. I noticed that I had to define in interface every method that could be possibly needed. For example, I can have `getUser(String name)`, but if I want `getAllUsers()`, I could not implement it using `getUser(String name)` because I don't know in advance all the user's names. So I must add `getAllUsers()` to IDatasource.
If I'd do this for every new method (e.g. getting only some users that match certain criteria), it would soon become a mess.
I thought of always getting all the users and do a filtering in code, but that doesn't make much sense.
Is there a simpler solution to this or I'm left with huge interface?

Comment: You can use in this case `GetAllCustomers` and then do a select on those one, in order not to increase the number of the methods in your interface. And of course, this approach is not the most performant way, as it gets all the customers from database.

Comment: Yes I know, I wrote that in a question. I wouldn't make much sense not to use database engine's queries/filtering.

Comment: *it would soon become a mess*: why would it? That's basically what everybody does: putting data access logic in specific DAO/repository classes. It only becomes a mess if you put all methods of all entities in the same class. If you define a UserDao, a ProductDao, an OrderDao, etc. then it shouldn't be such a mess.

Comment: https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the problematics of the DAO pattern. The interface tends to bloat because its limits are not well specified.

A better alternative is to use the Repository pattern. The ingenuity here is the use of specifications for selecting the correct set of results. With this pattern it is not likely that you will need to add new methods very often.

```
public interface AccountRepository {
    void addAccount(Account account);
    void removeAccount(Account account);
    void updateAccount(Account account); // Think it as replace for set
    List query(AccountSpecification specification); 
}
```

For more details I recommend reading this article: https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the SQL part. Should I have one query() method for SqlSpecification too or make it extends AccountSpecification interface? How can code that uses AccountRepository interface see SqlSpecification interface of AccountSpecificationByAgeRange class?